# Is there any good quality and reliable site on the web (other than this one) to ask Christian questions?

Tags: discussion

I want (want emphatically) to know the answers to certain questions regarding joy and Heaven. As it is, these questions do not suit this site as they are more Christian ministery type ones or ask for the general opinions held by the majority of Christians (opinions none the less, no less so just because they are commonly held). I'm getting nowhere with this site- it's perfectly good at what it does but I'm in danger of driving you all up the wall. But, for the life of me, where else to turn!- I cannot seem to find a single reliable site on the web to recieve good Christian answers!
And before someone votes THIS down (or closes it down), it IS a Christian question, it's asking where specifically to turn when filled with questions. It isn't asking for an opinion- either a site WILL answer such questions or it won't.

I would love to find a site where I can recieve answers from 'experts' (rather than fellow amateurs like myself!) whos knowledge I can trust.

Comment: The most obvious answer is going to be that you find an Internet discussion forum or that you find a Bible Study group in a church near you, preferably one that is led by an educated pastor.

Comment: Your best bet is a local pastor. If that's a problem then you can try a local interfaith discussion group.

Answer (score 6):

I think Anonymous actually hit it in comments here. Your basic problem is that the internet is not the place to find truth. It's a great source of reference material and you can learn all sorts of things from and about other people and groups. **The trouble is God doesn't have an account on this site or any other.** Ergo you won't find definitive answers to questions about things where He is the only expert.

That does't mean God is silent. There is a place where He reveals himself: you will definitive answers (not to every question but to the ones that you need to know the answers to) in his Word through the guidance of His spirit. As such the context to place yourself in to discern these things is a community of faith of folks that rely first and foremost on his word and in whom His spirit lives. This is one of the primary purposes of the Church. Find yourself a local one where the Word is faithfully preached and lived and where His guidance through the Spirit is sought.

Comment: Thanks. The local one is a bit vicarless at present but sound advise none the less!

Answer (score -5):

There is no "Christian" web site, local religious assembly "Christian" or otherwise nor any supportive expert associated to these contemporary religious systems that have any possibility of providing the answer that you intuitively know to exist. You cannot find the correct answer from any of them. For the primary factoid that is present in the true soteriological system that has been established and put into effect by the unlawful crucifixion of Jesus Christ is that this system does not allow a rejection of the system's protocol without also committing a sin that is not forgivable.

Comment: So when are you going to start a church?

Comment: Have no intention of starting a church and you are fully aware of my soterical position. That it differs from the common assumptive? Very few ever find the gate, friend, according to Him. So defense of the common assumption is not to your credit. Besides we've already had this discussion.

Comment: I just figured that you might think it is something you should do *in light of* your 'soterical position'. Maybe you had this discussion with someone else.

Comment: I suggest that you confine your comments to me to doctrinal differences. Whatever I do or do not do is not a matter that concerns you.

Comment: Well, if you started a church and I wanted to join, then it does concern me. Also, if you started a church and self-identified as christian I could ask questions on this site "according to the church of Theodore A. Jones." So you see, this is related to doctrine. I would actually like to know what exactly you believe, why you think it is such a rarity, and specifically what one should do to gain access into heaven. The problem, is that I still do not understand most of what you say, especially in chat, which is where you have spent most of your time.

Comment: "For it is not those who hear the law who are righteous in God's sight, but it is those who obey the law who will be declared righteous." Rom. 2:13 
Freddy. If you understood the significance of only this one statement you would already be in the church I'm in. Why should I attempt to start a church?